# Как получить от postgres массив записей, а не запись массивом?

Tags: php, postgresql

Делаю на PHP запрос к базе, чтобы найти запись, где код города вылета и код города прибытия равняются тем, которые были запрошены пользователем:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM special_offers WHERE to_iata = '{$to_iata}' AND from_iata = '{$from_iata}'";
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
```

Сейчас у меня в базе всего по одной записи подходящих данных есть, но я не могу понять, как мне их правильно достать.

Я обрабатываю данные, пытаясь собрать значения одного конкретного ключа в массив:

```
$rows = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    array_push($hashes, $row['data_hash']);
}
```

Но на деле оказалось, что одна запись предоставляется не в виде вложенного массива с нулевым  индексом, а просто в виде одиночного массива в формате **ключ=>значение**. Как мне правильно запросить данные из БД, чтобы мне приходил массив записей, а не одна запись массивом? Пробовал вместо `pg_fetch_assoc()` использовать `pg_fetch_array()`, но это ничего не изменило, лишь добавились дополнительные ключи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть функция [`pg_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-fetch-all.php) возвращающая именно массив всех записей.

А [`pg_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php), как и указано в мануале, возвращает одну строку результата. Для получения следующей необходимо вызвать `pg_fetch_assoc` ещё раз и так до тех пор пока функция не вернёт `false`. В общем-то, как и в других PHP библиотеках доступа к базам данных.

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['id'];
  echo $row['author'];
  echo $row['email'];
}
```

Вы же скорей всего ищете вовсе функцию [`pg_fetch_all_columns`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-fetch-all-columns.php) которая вернёт сразу готовый массив из значений определённой колонки.